# 3 Column page with Left/0 and right/2 section-subsection-subsubsection numbering issues

Tags: sectioning, numbering, multicol

I may be doing this completely wrong, but I am trying to learn to write a form of process/workflow/framework. I am using a three-column page format, trying to keep the same section per page where:

1. left/0 column has a section, subsection, and subsubsection with a continuous numbering scheme.
2. center/1 column a graphic workflow.
3. right/2 column has subsection, subsubsection, and items. (here the numbering scheme is not subsequent from "left/0 column")

What could I be missing or doing wrong?

Any help to help me understand what I am doing wrong or what package I should look into to figure out my mistake will be appreciated.

[image]

```
\newpage

\begin{paracol}{3} % Create 3 columns
\switchcolumn[0]* % Switch to the left column (0-indexed)

\section{Quick Change Task Form}
\subsection{Key Details on the Publication Form}
\subsubsection{Title: automatically set at assigned by workflow}
\subsubsection{RequestID: new numbering scheme automatically set by workflow.}
\subsubsection{Requested By: the person who submitted the request.}
\subsubsection{Assigned To: the assigned person defined during assignment by Standards Manager.}
\subsubsection{Peer Reviewer: the peer reviewer defined during assignment by Standards Manager.}
\subsubsection{Status: automatically set by workflow.}
\subsubsection{Open Date: date in which the quick-change task was created; automatically set by workflow.}
\subsubsection{Revision Date: date in which the last revision to the quick-change task took place; automatically set by workflow.}
\subsubsection{Target Date: target resolution date defined during the assignment by Standards Manager.}
\subsubsection{Hide Attachments: Show/hide the attachments section.}

% Store the last subsubsection counter value
\edef\storedsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\switchcolumn[2] % Switch to the left column (0-indexed)

% Restore the stored subsubsection counter value
\setcounter{subsubsection}{\storedsubsection}

\subsection{Quick Change Task Overview}
\subsubsection{Creation}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Task is created from a closed ETSR
\item Alternatively, Standards team members can submit a request.
\item Also automatically created as part of a Project if the “Create Quick Change” checkbox is checked when creating development tasks during Planning.
\item Status = Submitted.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Assignment}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Standards Manager sets Assigned To, approver, and publisher, as well as other assignment details.
\item RTL is responsible for defining assignment details for quick-change tasks that are part of a project.
\item Status changes to assigned
\item Alternatively, standards manager can close right away
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Development}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Assigned to drafts the deliverables to meet the scope of the request.
\item Assigned to resolves the quick-change tasks and adds resolution details
\item If development, status changes to under review
\item Other resolution options include moved to dashboard, deferred, duplicate, not accepted, and no longer needed; status changes to closed.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Assignment}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The quick-change tasks process does not include a peer review.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Approval}
\begin{enumerate}
\item If approval is required (decided by standards manager during assignment), the approver reviews the quick-change task and adds approval details.
\item If not approved, quick-change task is assigned to, status changed to assigned, and the process repeats.
\item If approved, status changes to awaiting publishing.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Publishing}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Publisher moves the completed deliverables to the appropriate publication location and adds publishing details.
\item Status changes to published.
\end{enumerate}

\switchcolumn[1] % Switch to the left column (0-indexed)

\begin{adjustbox}{vcenter,center}

% Define block and line styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!25, text=black, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=5em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

% Create the TikZ picture environment
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.5cm, auto]

    % Creates the blocks
    \node [block, fill=gray!25] (sec1) {Creation};
    \node [block, fill=red!25!gray!85, below of=sec1] (sec2) {Assignment};
    \node [block, fill=red!35!gray!45, below of=sec2] (sec3) {Development};
    \node [block, fill=red!45!gray!55, below of=sec3] (sec4) {No Peer Review};
    \node [block, fill=red!55!gray!65, below of=sec4] (sec5) {Approval};
    \node [block, fill=red!65!gray!75, below of=sec5] (sec6) {Publishing};

% Connect the blocks with lines
\path [line] (sec1) -- (sec2);
\path [line] (sec2) -- (sec3);
\path [line] (sec3) -- (sec4);
\path [line] (sec4) -- (sec5);
\path [line] (sec5) -- (sec6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{paracol}{3} % Create 3 columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: Depending on your application, the `raster` library of `tcolorbox` may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

The [`paracol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) package is intended for typesetting contents in *para*llel, the manual is an example of this typesetting results and source, other examples would be simultaneous typesetting a translation.
This generally means reproducing the same contents in different columns and so labelling runs locally to each column.

The package provides `\globalcounter{<counter>}` which uses the same counter across all columns.
In your example this would call for `\globalcounter{section}` and `\globalcounter{subsection}`, in general you may need to promote any other counters used in your code to make the columns appear continuous.

Alternatively you can set `\syncallcounters` before `\switchcolumn` as a catch-all synchronisation of counters between columns.
There is no `\globalallcounters` equivalent though, so this must be issued before every `\switchcolumn` that may have incremented a counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\globalcounter{section}
\globalcounter{subsection}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{3} % Create 3 columns
\switchcolumn[0]* % Switch to the left column (0-indexed)

\section{Quick Change Task Form}
\subsection{Key Details on the Publication Form}
\subsubsection{Title: automatically set at assigned by workflow}
\subsubsection{RequestID: new numbering scheme automatically set by workflow.}

\syncallcounters
\switchcolumn[2] % Switch to the left column (0-indexed)

\subsection{Quick Change Task Overview}
\subsubsection{Creation}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Task is created from a closed ETSR
\item Alternatively, Standards team members can submit a request.
\item Also automatically created as part of a Project if the “Create Quick Change” checkbox is checked when creating development tasks during Planning.
\item Status = Submitted.
\end{enumerate}
\subsubsection{Assignment}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Standards Manager sets Assigned To, approver, and publisher, as well as other assignment details.
\item RTL is responsible for defining assignment details for quick-change tasks that are part of a project.
\item Status changes to assigned
\item Alternatively, standards manager can close right away
\end{enumerate}

\switchcolumn[1] % Switch to the left column (0-indexed)

\centering

% Define block and line styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!25, text=black, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=5em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

% Create the TikZ picture environment
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.5cm, auto]

    % Creates the blocks
    \node [block, fill=gray!25] (sec1) {Creation};
    \node [block, fill=red!25!gray!85, below of=sec1] (sec2) {Assignment};
    \node [block, fill=red!35!gray!45, below of=sec2] (sec3) {Development};
    \node [block, fill=red!45!gray!55, below of=sec3] (sec4) {No Peer Review};
    \node [block, fill=red!55!gray!65, below of=sec4] (sec5) {Approval};
    \node [block, fill=red!65!gray!75, below of=sec5] (sec6) {Publishing};

% Connect the blocks with lines
\path [line] (sec1) -- (sec2);
\path [line] (sec2) -- (sec3);
\path [line] (sec3) -- (sec4);
\path [line] (sec4) -- (sec5);
\path [line] (sec5) -- (sec6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code showing column 1 beginning with Section 1 and column 3 beginning with Subsection 1.2]