Paracol not numbering properly
Thank you for helping.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\begin{parts}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\part $a question$
\fillwithlines{1cm}
\switchcolumn

\part $a question$
\fillwithlines{1cm}
\switchcolumn

\part $a question$
\fillwithlines{1cm}
\switchcolumn

\part $a question$
\fillwithlines{1cm}

\end{paracol}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}
\end{document}

When I compile the output shows this.

I notice that the numbering is not accurate for the parts. How could I fix this so it goes
a, b
c, d
e, f
I know multicols and other things might fix this but I want to use paracol specifically.
Thank you

Unrelated: don't use $a question$ if you want italic text, use \textit{a question} instead. The $ introduces math mode which influences the spacing of the letters, here you can see in the screenshot that the space between a and question is missing in the output.

See also \globalcounter (page 6).

The idea of the paracol package is to provide multiple columns that are typeset in parallel (hence the name of the package). Therefore, it is totally logical that the counters are reset for all columns.
You can place the \syncallcounters command just before \switchcolumn to tell the package to resume the counters when switching to the next column. To simplify typesetting, you can create a custom command for this:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand{\myswitchcol}{
    \syncallcounters\switchcolumn
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{parts}

\part \emph{a question}
\fillwithlines{1cm}
\myswitchcol

\part \emph{a question}
\fillwithlines{1cm}
\myswitchcol

\part \emph{a question}
\fillwithlines{1cm}
\myswitchcol

\part \emph{a question}
\fillwithlines{1cm}

\end{parts}
\end{paracol}

\end{questions}
\end{document}


However, note that there are two problems in your code example:

The parts environment should be placed inside the paracol environment and not the other way around.
As already mentioned in the comments: You probably don't want to use math mode ($...$) to italicize text, but \emph{...}. The former uses a different spacing mechanism suitable for math, but not for plain text.


Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680000/47927
